# The use of "except"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Here is a sentence I saw using the word except:

> valid claims were granted patent to land free and clear, except for a small registration fee.

What does it mean? How does the word except here related the registration fee to the previous part of the sentence.

Comment: Many questions of this type can be answered with a dictionary. If the dictionary definition of [except](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/except) doesn't help, please edit the question to explain what is unclear to you.

Comment: The sentence is in legal English; the phrase _granted patent to land_ and _free and clear_ are fixed legal expressions. The _free and clear_ phrase, meaning 'no payment required', is modified by the prepositional phrase _except for a small registration fee_. The meaning is as @Liesmith gives it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The land is free, with the exception of a small fee you must pay.  So, in this context, the land is not actually free.